# Onkeydown what's the diference between return false and return super.onkeydown()?

Tags: android

I put a list view inside a linearlayout,and I want to override onkeydown() method in ListView
,and I don't control the focus, just change some variables in onkeydown(),I want system do as if I haven't override the onkeydown method.what should I do?return false? or return super.onkeyDown()?.It will be very nice for any help. thank you in advance.

[image]

there are three listviews,and a b c are three item of listviews. when c is focused, when I press left arrow on keybord, then a get focus by default. And I want the first item in listview2 get focus how can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ntc** is not exactly correct.  OS does not use reflection to get your base class' handler.

If you return false, you explicitly tell OS that you do not want to handle this event; OS calls the View's parent handler then (as your test shows); this happens until event got handled or top View is reached.

If you call super.OnKeyDown() you allow your base class to process event. Note that it's a base class' handler serving same view, not parent view; don't confuse here.

So, using one or the other depends on your view's behavior desired.

I supose in your case you need `return super.onKeyDown();`

Comment: yes, you are right ,I got it.and in my case I should return super.onkeydown().But i have found that the focus changes always don not like what I want.

Comment: If UI does not allow you to, you may want to think twice if this is what you want. User should not be confused of unexpected UI behavior.

Comment: system's focus change by default can make users confused, what I want is only to adjust it normal..I will post a picture to make it clear

Comment: sorry for that my account's reputation is 5 less than 10 , I can not add a picture in my question....

Comment: This should now probably be another question :)  Note that Android works in two modes: focusable and focus-less. These two switch depending on user input: it user presses a key on a keypad - it turns into focusable mode; if user touches screen - it turns into focus-less mode. In focus-less mode there's **NO** list items focused.

Comment: em, it's my fault ,I didn't make it clear, it always be controled by keyboard not by touch screen .

Answer (score 1):

`super.onkeyDown()`- this puts the burden on super class to handle the `onKeyDown` event by your own wish (You explicitly say to handle it). when you return `false`, android assumes  that you have not handled the `onKeyDown` event and `super.onKeyDown()` gets called by default (without you calling it).

Comment: em...maybe when return false, the parent view not parent class will handled the onkeyDown.

Comment: em..I just create a FileListView class which is extends listview.And I put it in a linearlayout. if onkeydow, retrun flase.then linearlayout will handle it,if return super.onkeydown,listView will handle it?right ?that it my comprehension which i'm not sure.